# How to fix a warning error from perl mongodb script

Tags: mongodb, perl

I am using perl mongodb module to connect to mongdb and pull the records from collection Account after a certain time such as '2020-07-17 16:15:16'.

The collection Account is like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0e13e475a2f6784114b68t”),
    "subscriber" : “1234567890”,
    "time_stamp" : "2020-07-14T20:21:53Z",
    "time" : ISODate("2020-07-14T20:21:53.407Z")
}
```

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;
use DateTime;
use JSON;
use MongoDB;

  my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new( host => '127.0.0.1', port => 27017 );
  my $db_name = 'test';

   my $database = $client->get_database($db_name);
   my $collection = $database->get_collection('account');


   my $start_date = '2020-07-17 16:15:16';
   my $dt_start= convert_string_datetime($start_date);


   foreach my $e ($collection->find( {time => { '$gte' => $dt_start }}) ->all) {
      my $subscriber = $e->{subscriber};
      print "sub=$subscriber \n";
}
exit(0);

sub convert_string_datetime
{
    my $str =$_[0];
    my $year;
    my $four_digit_year;
    my $month;
    my $day;
    my $day_and_time;
    my $time;
    my $mins;
    my $hrs;
    my $secs;

    ($four_digit_year,$month,$day_and_time)=split(/-/,$str);
    ($day,$time)=split(/ /,$day_and_time); #split the date and time
    ($hrs,$mins,$secs)=split(/:/,$time);

    my $dt = DateTime->new(
                        year   => $four_digit_year,
                        month  => $month,
                        day    => $day,
                        hour   => $hrs,
                        minute => $mins,
                        second => $secs,
                        );
    return $dt;
}
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. I used the subroutine to convert the time string to the datetime which can be used to compare  "time" : ISODate in the collection Account. when I run the above code, it correctly pull the records I want but give a warning error. I don't know how to fix it:

   saving floating timezone as UTC at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/MongoDB/BSON.pm line 218
2. The above code works fine to connect to the localhost. But it fails when I try to connect to a remote host to access mongodb within same network such as 192.168.x.x such as:

   my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new( host => '192.168.10.24', port => 27017 );

   What is the best way to connect to a remote host within same 192.168* network?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Perhaps firewall blocks port 27017 on network interface 192.168.10.24. Scan port 27017 on interface 192.168.10.24 from remote host on same network -- result of scan should confirm if the port is filtered out by firewall.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How to scan port 27017 on interface 192.168.10.24?

Comment: Read [documentation](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/project/opssrc/nmap-3.00/docs/nmap_manpage.html) for [nmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap). Nmap command [examples](https://www.cyberciti.biz/security/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/).

Answer (score 1):

You are storing a local time  (time without time zone) in MongoDB but MongoDB only supports UTC timestamps. The warning tells you that the local time is converted to UTC before being stored.

Comment: Thanks fro your reply. Any idea how to get rid of the warning message?

Comment: What happens you add time zone info to the DateTime object?

Comment: I added:   $dt->set_time_zone( 'local' ); The waring message disappeared. Thanks!